# Why can't I animate a cloned element?

Tags: jquery, animation, clone

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/LupfW/) :

```
var newElement=$('.oggetto').eq(0).clone();
newElement.animate({ 'top': '2000px'}, 5000);

<div id="container">
    <div class="oggetto" style="left:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="oggetto" style="left:50px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

but seems that ".oggetto" won't to move after the clone().

In fact, if I just write :

```
$('.oggetto').eq(0).animate({ 'top': '2000px'}, 5000);
```

it works as well. Where am I wrong?

Comment: how can you move something that is not injected into the dom? `newelement` is a reference of a clone, it's not a reference of `oggetto`

Comment: tried also .appendTo() after the clone, but it still doesnt works

Comment: @markzzz don't lie, my jsfiddle does just that and it works :P

Comment: yeah @Esailija : I was just append it in a wrong way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, first the cloned element have to inserted into the DOM and then should be animated.

```
var newElement=$('.oggetto').eq(0).clone();
$("#container").append(newElement); //add the element 

//Now animate
newElement.animate({ 'top': '2000px'}, 5000);
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LupfW/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting it to the DOM before animating it...

http://jsfiddle.net/LupfW/1/

```
newElement.appendTo("body").animate({ 'top': '2000px'}, 5000);​
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append it to the dom tree. ***[THE DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/LupfW/2/)***

```
newElement.appendTo('#container').animate({ 'top': '2000px'}, 5000);​
```